# Does the Silverlight toolkit Line Chart enable line smoothing?

Tags: silverlight, charts, silverlight-toolkit

I'm working on some charting, and am currently using the Silverlight Toolkit.  At the moment the line series links all the datapoints with straight lines, making for a fairly jagged display.

Is there a way for the chart to apply smoothing to the line series?

If not, does anyone have any other suggestions?  Are there other charting packages which you can suggest which would offer better functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found these charts from [Visifire](http://visifire.com/silverlight_charts_gallery.php) that fit [splines](http://visifire.com/silverlight_spline_charts_gallery.php) through the data points. Though they are paid for unless you go with the "Community" license, but you might not agree to it's [terms](http://visifire.com/license.php)